# Null cert chain error, yet certs exist and are correct

Tags: ssl, glassfish, certificate, ssl-certificate, jks

I have four servers communicating in a series, each transporting data over a two way ssl connection. Currently the certs are self-signed.

Server A sends data to B, which processes and sends to C, which sends to the recipient D.

A and B have exchanged certs, and can communicate over two-way ssl just fine.

C and D have exchanged certs, and can communicate over two-way ssl just fine.

B and C have exchanged certs, but C throws a `null cert chain` error.

C receives the `ClientHello`, sends a `ServerHello`, and sends it's cert. It then follows with the `CertificateRequest`, and the `ServerHelloDone`.

B receives the cert, as well as the certificate request. It writes back a response of 77 bytes, which seems small.

I am using Glassfish as the server, and it appears there is a bug that causes much of the logged data to be split up into two byte chunks, making it hard to get an exact read on what gets sent back.

C receives the response, and promptly throws a `null cert chain` error, and closes the connection.

The CN's sent back over the CertificatRequest match the CN in both the truststore and the keystore. The md5's match, and the servers are able to communicate with other servers, just not each other.

Let me know what additional data I can provide to give greater insight, if needed.